# Error while installing WSO2 EMM on windows for Android

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I use the command wso2server.bat --run, the error is as follows

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_131
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Users\MCCHEE~1\DOWNLO~1\WSO2EM~1.0\bin..
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

I have read previous questions on stackoverflow regarding the issue. But no luck with finding any solution. Please help me resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: I usually place JDK and product (wso2emm) to directories without spaces

Comment: I dont have any spaces in the path for both JDK and Wso2 EMM.But no improvement in the result. Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is an actual thing that could be done, but this is what I did.

- Downloaded Wso2 IoT pacakge from [WSO2 IoT downloads](http://wso2.com/iot/)
- replaced the bin folder of Wso2EMM with bin folder from Wso2Iot/core.

This helped me. No errors clean run.